# R, matrices: subtract maximum row-wise, removing NAs

Tags: r, matrix, max, vectorization

Given a non-square matrix `a` I need to subtract from each row its own maximum. The matrix contains `NA`s, to be discarded. The dimensions of the matrix are known in advance and fixed. Also, all `NA`s are under the main diagonal, if this info helps, that is, `a` has the form

```
a11 a12 a13 a14 ...
NA  a22 a23 a24 ...
NA  NA  a33 a34 ...
...
```

For the moment I'm using

`a <- a - apply(a,1,function(x){max(x, na.rm=TRUE)})`

(which incidentally is faster than `t(apply(a,1,function(x){x-max(x, na.rm=TRUE)}))`).

I wonder if there's a faster solution, because this operation will have to be repeated very many times.

In Stackoverflow I found answers to similar questions, suggesting to use `pmax`, but that would require converting the matrix to a list, and that would make it much slower than my solution, I believe. Some answers suggested using `rowwise` from `dplyr`, but that seems to require converting the matrix to a data frame first.

Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `rowMaxs` from `matrixStats` package which is usually faster

```
a - matrixStats::rowMaxs(a, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Fantastic, about 8 times faster than `apply`! Even faster if `matrixStats` is loaded first. Thank you.